# Non-deterministic output from MATLAB perfcurve function

Tags: matlab, roc

I cannot figure out why this is happening, but it may be a bug?

My data is 10 classes each with 1287 observations. For some reason [`perfcurve()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html) returns 1288-dimensional `t`'s and `f`'s. However, the sixth iteration returns 1287 dimensional ones. As a result I cannot assign to the `tpr` and `fpr` matrices directly (or indirectly as shown below). What's the deal?

Here's my code.

```
load('gt.mat')
load('scores.mat')
num_tests = 1287;
tpr = zeros(10, num_tests+1);
fpr = zeros(10, num_tests+1);
AUC = zeros(10, 1);
for i = 1 : 10
    i
    [t, f, ~, AUC(i)] = perfcurve(gt(:,i), scores(:,i), 1);
    tpr(i,:) = t;
    fpr(i,:) = f;
end
```

Here are [`scores.mat`](http://www.filedropper.com/scores) and [`gt.mat`](http://www.filedropper.com/gt).

Comment: I have no experience with perfcruve, but I'm quite sure that I've read somewhere before that perfcurve returns N+1 points for input with N points. I can't say 100% for sure, though.

Anyway, a possible "solution" for your problem, given that the data  returned from the function is as you expect, is to assign in the following way: tpr(i;1:length(t)) = t (and similarly for fpr). I have no explanation for the behavior, but at least this allows you to run your code.

Comment: Tried using cell arrays instead, e.g. tpr = cell(10,1), fpr = cell(10,1) and assigning directly with 

[tpr{i,:}, fpr{i,:}, ~, AUC(i)] = perfcurve(gt(:,i), scores(:,i), 1);

This works as well, giving you arrays with no overhead in size (extra zeros). Examining the output you'll see that the 9th iteration produce a 1246-by-1 array, thus using a 1277 (or 1278)-by-1 array to store those values will give you a lot of excess zeros.

Plot data;
figure;hold on; cellfun(@plot,tpr,fpr);

Comment: @ritualmagick: My fall back is to use cell arrays, but it still doesn't explain what's happening though